# Lightswitch many-to-many preprocessquery method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, many-to-many, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm having  a problem with preprocessquery for many-to-many relationship DB.

The DB model looks like this:

Player [1]---[N] PlayerMatch [N]-----[1] Match

So **Player** can have many **Matches** and the **Match** can have many **Player** attached using **PlayerMatch** table.

Using preprocessquery I want to return only oponents for given **Player.Id**.

1. Take all elements of Match instance for given PlayerID
2. Take all elements from PlayerMatch where `PlayerMatch.Match.ID == records` from (1) and return that PlayerMatch.Player instaces

I think of:

```
partial void PlayerOponents_PreprocessQuery(int? PlayerID, ref IQueryable<Player> query)
{
     var playerGames = from g in this.PlayerMatches
                       where g.Player.Id == PlayerID 
                       select g.Match;
     var oponents    = from m in this.PlayerMatches
                       where (from g in playerGames where m.Match.Id == g.Id select m)
                       select m.Player;
     query = oponents;
}
```

How do I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve it. Problem was that Lightswitch supports only subset of LINQ.
There are a few restrictions for complex queries.

```
var oponentList = new List<Player>();
var matches = (from q in this.PlayerMatches where q.Players.Id == PlayerID select q.Matches).Execute();
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    var oponents = (from q in this.PlayerMatches where q.Matches.Id == match.Id where q.Players.Id != PlayerID select q.Players).Execute();
    foreach (Player player in oponents)
    {
        oponentList.Add(player);
    }              
}
query = oponentList.AsQueryable().Take(oponentList.Count());
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

My below code wasn't actually working correctly...it was just returning the first X number of people in the database and ignoring the actual contents of the list that I manually populated. (Perhaps it would have worked with an earlier version of Lightswitch; see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3db15a5f-aedd-4619-a0cc-d9580a9cd921/can-i-replace-iqueryablemonthlybalance-query-with-generic-list-asqueryable-in-preprocessquery?forum=lightswitch.)

This is the code I'm using now (which works correctly):

```
Role trainerRole = (from r in Roles where r.Name == "Trainer" select r).Single();
var trainerIds = trainerRole.PersonRoles.Select(pr => pr.Person.Id);
query = query.Where(p => trainerIds.Contains(p.Id));
```

---

Thanks very much for posting your answer. It helped me figure out a good solution for my situation, which was a bit simpler:

```
partial void Trainers_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<Person> query)
{
    var trainers = new List<Person>();
    Role trainerRole = (from r in Roles where r.Name == "Trainer" select r).Single();
    foreach (PersonRole pr in trainerRole.PersonRoles)
    {
        trainers.Add(pr.Person);
    }
    query = trainers.AsQueryable().Take(trainers.Count());
}
```